# Rotate sidewaystable (twoside option): Top of table to the left

Tags: floats, double-sided, rotating

I have 3 sidewaystable's in a row, but have broken up the table into 3 separate tables, each of one page (much easier). I'm using the twoside option for the document. But this seems to affect the rotation of the tables: What I want, is that the top of the table is always to the left, when you read the thesis, so you can read through two tables with out turning the paper.

I am thinking of something like `\rotatebox{180}` or `\begin{rotate}{180}`, but this doesn't seem to work, as the rotation axis is in the middle (or something?), or because I put it in the wrong place? This is the beginning of my table:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{report} 

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}\footnotesize
\caption{}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\advance\hsize9em}X
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\advance\hsize9em}X
X
X
X
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\advance\hsize4em}X
>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\advance\hsize8em}X 
}
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & ... \\
```

Does any one have a hint?

Answer (score 8):

Use the `figuresright` option of the `rotating` package. See secion 2.1 of the manual for details.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}

\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}

\newcommand*{\dummysidewaystable}{%
  \begin{sidewaystable}
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
  Knuth & Lamport
  \end{tabular}
  \end{sidewaystable}
}

\begin{document}

\dummysidewaystable

\dummysidewaystable

\dummysidewaystable

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem! Just to make sure, what exactly does this package do to the document? I mean, it seems like it's only my sidewaystable's that have been changed (what I wanted!), but am I missing another change?