# Option clash for package rotating

Tags: tables, rotating, double-sided, sidewaystable

I am using this thesis template and `sidewaystable` environments provided by the `rotating` package. However, I have a two-sided document, and I have two `sidewaystable` environments, one on each page, which not rotated in the sme direction. Instead, one `sidewaystable` is rotated to the right and the other to the left.

[This post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86390/rotate-sidewaystable-twoside-option-top-of-table-to-the-left) explains a similar problem. The solution to it is to add:

```
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
```

to the preamble. However, I get a strange error when I add the above line to this [thesis template](https://github.com/mcmanigle/OxThesis). The error says:

```
Option clash for package rotating.
```

Can anyone point to me what is the problem? Which option does it clash with?

Comment: note that the solution suggested by Mico's answer is exactly the solution suggested by latex if you type `h` to the error message....

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to line 131 in the file [ociamthesis.cls](https://github.com/mcmanigle/OxThesis/blob/master/ociamthesis.cls), the LaTeX document class you employ, the `rotating` package is loaded automatically, but without any options. When LaTeX encounters the directive `\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}` in the preamble of your document, it issues a warning message since packages shouldn't be loaded repeatedly with inconsistent (let alone mutually conflicting) options

The solution is to set `figuresright` as one of the options of the `\documentclass` directive at the very top of your document:

```
\documentclass[figuresright,<any other options>]{ociamthesis}
```

Options specified at the `\documentclass` stage will get passed to subsequent `\usepackage` statements automatically.

If you follow this route, there will be no need for a separate `\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}` directive in the preamble of your document.